# how to write a recursion to locate a value in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a recursive function to locate a value within a multidimensional array. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var locate = function (arr,value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === value) {
            return true;
        } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            locate(arr[i], value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, it isn't working:

```
console.log(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'e'))
// => returns `false`, but should return `true`
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: when i add a return, this case, which should be true, becomes false




    console.log(locate(['a', ['b'], 'c'], 'c'))

Comment: Oh, put it in a conditional and return only if that call returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive DFS:

```
var locate = function (arr, value) {
    // start at the current array; we want to check every value
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // if we've found our value, return immediately
        if (arr[i] === value) {
            return true;
        // if the element is an array, call locate on the element
        // and possibly return true
        // we don't want to return locate(arr[i], value) because
        // it could be found later on
        } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) && locate(arr[i], value)) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    // reached the end of the current array, so return `false`
    // note, since we use `else if (... locate(arr[i], value)),
    // we won't stop the recursion before checking every possible value
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this solution passed all the test cases! the other ones didn't. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var locate = function(arr,value){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === value) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      var value = locate(arr[i], value);
      if(value === true){
         return true;
      }
    }
  }
   return false;
}

console.log(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'e'))
```

It is not that your  recursion was off.
It was that you ignored the return value and eventually returned false either way.

So you need to return the result of the recursion in case you recurse.

Comment: By returning `locate(arr[i], value)`, you possibly cut the recursion short, ignoring the rest of the initial array. You only want to end the recursion if `locate(arr[i], value)` returns `true`. Otherwise, you keep going.

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that. Was too focused on just making his example work.

Answer (score 0):

Even if one of the nested calls to locate() returns true, you're just throwing that value away.

```
var locate = function(haystack, needle) {
  for (var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(haystack[i])) {
      if (locate(haystack[i], needle)) {
          return true;
      }
    } else if (haystack[i] === needle) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Wrong, try `locate([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 7], 7)`